# Batch Script - Ampersand & space

Tags: batch-file

Running a batch script for Anaplan connect and the referenced directory has a & and space. I have tried using ^ to escape the & but no luck

```
@echo off
set AnaplanUser=""
set WorkspaceId=""
set ModelId=""
set ServiceUrl="https://api.anaplan.com"
set AuthUrl="https://auth.anaplan.com"
set FileName="PL.CSV"
set FilePath= "C:\Users\mturkenburg\WHISPIR\Gareth Edlin - FP^&A\Anaplan\anaplan-connect\PL.CSV"
set ImportName="Upload Management PL"
set DumpName= "C:\Users\mturkenburg\WHISPIR\Gareth Edlin - FP^&A\Anaplan\anaplan-connect\errors.txt"
set Chunksize=50

set Operation=-debug -service %ServiceUrl% -auth %AuthUrl% -workspace %WorkspaceId% -model %ModelId% -chunksize %Chunksize% -file %FileName% -put %FilePath% -import %ImportName% -execute -output %DumpName%
```

Comment: Apart from needless setting of variables which is really inefficient, you don't need to and shouldn't escape `&` enclosed in quotes. That is a one line command.

Comment: This is the setup for the Anaplan Connect batch file upload. I have merely entered in my data. I believe I do need to escape the & because I receive an error from the A after the & when the file is run

Comment: `Echo "cat&dog"` then `echo cat&dog`.

Comment: It's not possible to help, because the code you shown doesn't have any problems with ampersands at all. The error occurs in another part, that is the relevant part to decide how you should modify your variables.

Answer (score 0):

> - I'm not sure if I've understood this question, but...

- Try test this result by using  **[`substring`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)** with replace: **`set "Operation=!_Operation:?=&!"`**

  ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "AnaplanUser="" "
set "WorkspaceId="" "
set "ModelId="" "
set "ServiceUrl="https://api.anaplan.com" "
set "AuthUrl="https://auth.anaplan.com" "
set "FileName=PL.CSV"
set "FilePath=C:\Users\mturkenburg\WHISPIR\Gareth Edlin - FP ? \Anaplan\anaplan-connect\PL.CSV"
set "ImportName="Upload Management PL""
set "DumpName=C:\Users\mturkenburg\WHISPIR\Gareth Edlin - FP ? \Anaplan\anaplan-connect\errors.txt"
set "Chunksize=50"
set "_operation=-debug -service !ServiceUrl! -auth !AuthUrl! -workspace !WorkspaceId! -model !ModelId! -chunksize !Chunksize! -file "!FileName!" -put !FilePath! -import !ImportName! -execute -output "!DumpName!" "
set "Operation=!_Operation:?=&!"
echo(!Operation!
```

---

- Results:

  ---

```bat
-debug -service "https://api.anaplan.com"  -auth "https://auth.anaplan.com"  -workspace ""  -model ""  -chunksize 50 -file "PL.CSV" -put C:\Users\mturkenburg\WHISPIR\Gareth Edlin - FP & \Anaplan\anaplan-connect\PL.CSV -import "Upload Management PL" -execute -output "C:\Users\mturkenburg\WHISPIR\Gareth Edlin - FP & \Anaplan\anaplan-connect\errors.txt"
```

---

Comment: Your replace operation is superflouos, because there is no problem/difference in using the ampersand directly in the `SET "varname=aaa & bbb"`. The problem is the unknown usage of the `operation` and `FilePath` variable, later in the code

Comment: @jeb Thank you by comments, I’ve not sure about question, also, this intents to be didactic. If the error occurred are in not part of code in post (I think yes/no). Let’s wait to author appoint/describe more details for after see what is possible to do to help.